# sbt failed to compile "import ch.epfl.lamp.fjbg._"

Tags: scala, sbt

**scalac** is successed to compile this code.

```
import ch.epfl.lamp.fjbg._
```

But **sbt**(0.11.2) is failed to compile it.

```
[error] genbytecode.scala:2: not found: object ch
[error] import ch.epfl.lamp.fjbg._
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
```

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: You should post your `build.sbt` file...

Comment: In this case, I don't use build.sbt and Build.scala.

Comment: Then I don't understand how SBT can set the right classpath.

Comment: I create build.sbt and write
`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.1"`
work it! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The OP posted a comment:

> I create build.sbt and write `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.9.1"` work it! thank you.